# Scripting bash with Ruby and Variables to run FFMPEG command

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a simply ruby script to run an ffmpeg command through bash to convert an audio file from one format to another.

the command is `ffmpeg -i (in file) -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k -ar 48000 -ac 1 AAA_S00E00_Podcast.mp3`

I have a ruby script with the right permissions and that I can call (tested it with a `system ls` call before moving onto the ffmpeg attempt)

```
#!/bin/ruby

def mkmp3( one = "", two = "" )
    system "ffmpeg -i #{one} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k -ar 48000 -ac 1 #{two}.mp3"
end

mkmp3
```

but when I call it from bash trying to convert a file called `session.flac` to `smoochie.mp3` I get back:

```
mkmp3.rb ('session.flac', 'smoochie')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'session.flac','
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are using parenthesis `(` and `)` to add arguments to your ruby script. Remove them and the error will be gone; in fact, you only need to specify your strings separated by a space (otherwise you will get the comma `,` as a string):

```
$ mkmp3.rb session.flac smoochie
```

Now, to use those parameters you need to add `ARGV` in your script, like this:

```
#!/bin/ruby

def mkmp3( one = ARGV[0], two = ARGV[1] )
    system "ffmpeg -i #{one} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k -ar 48000 -ac 1 #{two}.mp3"
end

mkmp3
```

---

`ARGV` will contain an array of strings with the arguments you added, consider this script (`test.rb`):

```
#!/bin/ruby

puts ARGV.inspect
```

Execute the script:

```
$ ruby so.rb one two
```

And the output will be:

```
["one", "two"]
```

So you access each value using the array index (i.e. `ARGV[0]` and `ARGV[1]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass arguments to a function in your script by calling the script with parenthesized values.  You need to use `ARGV` to process arguments to the script.

I don't have `ffmpeg` on my system, so I'll illustrate how to use command-line args with a simple function that reports its arguments:

```
def my_function(first = "default1", second = "default2")
  puts "Args were #{first} and #{second}"
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME  # only invoke with ARGV if script is invoked directly
  my_function(*ARGV)  # flatten the ARGV array and pass all values
end
```

Produces the following when invoked with different numbers of arguments:

```
Desktop$ ruby argv_demo.rb 
Args were default1 and default2
Desktop$ ruby argv_demo.rb one
Args were one and default2
Desktop$ ruby argv_demo.rb one two
Args were one and two
Desktop$ ruby argv_demo.rb one two three
argv_demo.rb:1:in `my_function': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..2) (ArgumentError)
    from argv_demo.rb:6:in `<main>'
```